# Pointer to implementation (PIMPL) in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, dllexport, pimpl-idiom

I made a Dll with MSVS and used pimpl method successfuly exactly like below:

> Dll include file:

```
#include <memory>

#define DllExport __declspec( dllexport ) 

namespace M
{
    class P
    {
    public:
        DllExport P(/*some arguments*/);
        DllExport ~P();
        DllExport int aFunction (/* some arguments*/);

    private:
        class C;
        std::unique_ptr<C> mc;
    };
}
```

> The private include file:

```
namespace M
{
    class P::C
    {
        public:
         # Other variables and functions which are not needed to be exported...
    }
}
```

> And the cpp file:

```
DllExport M::P::P(/*some arguments*/):mc(std::make_unique<C>())
{
# ...
}
DllExport M::P::~P(){ }

DllExport int M::P::aFunction (/* some arguments*/)
{
#...
}
```

Now I want to implement such method in Qt creator. What changes I should make?

(I guess I have to use QScopedPointer instead of unique_ptr but what is best implementation form for that?)

PS: I set clang as compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `QScopedPointer` I managed to make it work like the way I wanted:

> Dll include:

```
#define DllExport __declspec( dllexport )

#include <QScopedPointer>

namespace M{
class PPrivate;

class P
{
public:
    DllExport P(/*some arguments*/);
    DllExport ~P();
    DllExport int aFunction (/* some arguments*/);

private:

    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(P)
    QScopedPointer<PPrivate> d_ptr;
};
}
```

> Private include:

```
namespace M
{
    class PPrivate
    {
        public:
            # Other variables and functions which are not needed to be exported...
    }
}
```

> The CPP file:

```
DllExport M::P::P(/*some arguments*/)
    :d_ptr(new PPrivate())
{ 
    #...
}
DllExport M::P::~P(){ }

DllExport int M::P::aFunction (/* some arguments*/)
{
    #...
}
```

Yet if somebody thinks there is a better idea, please share.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks find and it should be independent from the IDE.
You can use [this](https://agateau.com/2019/using-std-unique-ptr-with-qt/), but i think [this](https://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer) is what you are searching for.

Comment: Of course my own code was the first thing I tried. Didn't work.